# How do I open cacti?

Tags: snmp, cacti

I installed cacti on my laptop , running fedora . Installed it using yum install cacti . Hope that takes care of installing all the supporting tools.

Now I would like to know how to open the application and start using it . Anybody who has used cacti , could you please help me out ? Where will the executable for cacti be stored ? and how do i run it ? typing cacti on the command line did'nt work :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start reading the official documentation for linux/unix here: http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/install_unix.html
and the manuals here:
http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/

For a default Fedora installation, try open your browser at

http://localhost/cacti

and use the login/password that you have choosen during the installation

Follow the official documentation here:http://www.cacti.net/documentation.php

Comment: *cough* RTFM *cough*
to be completely honest if you can't manage to login to cacti, you may have a pretty hard time configuring it. It's very powerful but not really "easy".